# Why does this query take 32 sec to execute?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5, subquery, query-performance

I keep my history records in one table and my pertinent data in another. I want to grab only the files from `myfiles` that currently have a given status recorded in `statuses` (ie, the latest status is the one I want to filter by). I'm trying a subquery which may be a mistake, but I can't really think of another way to do it because there are many statuses for a given file in `myfiles`.

MySQL 5.0.96, column schema on both tables involved is fewer than 15.

< 500 records in `myfiles`, 68k records in `statuses`:

```
SELECT myfiles.*, 
(SELECT status FROM statuses WHERE statuses.itemtype=2 AND statuses.id=myfiles.id ORDER BY historyid DESC LIMIT 1) AS actualStatus
FROM myfiles
HAVING actualStatus=0
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8691) with the actual table schemas involved.
Thank you!

Comment: Edit your question with the `create table` DDL for each table in the query

Comment: @Phil i updated with a fiddle link to the actual schema. thanks!

Comment: I'd try adding an index on `(itemtype, id, historyid, status)`

Comment: @ypercube what do you mean? how do i do that? (i'm newish)

Comment: Unrelated but: why are you using `having` when you are not using `group by`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am by no means a db expert... i am using `HAVING` because i'm sorting by a calculated column, since i can't do a `WHERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to let you guys know what I did, thanks for responding. I ended up sticking with my original query but added keys to my table, which are apparently a thing I didn't know about. When I did

```
ALTER TABLE tblstatushistory
ADD KEY (id),
ADD KEY (itemtype)
```

It dropped the time waaaay down. Thanks for pointing me towards resources that taught me about `EXPLAIN` (or at least explained `EXPLAIN`) and about understanding indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually think about adding a status column to the table tblstockingorders and having a trigger on that table that injects the status into the tblstatushistory.

Granted you'd have to do a 1-time update to all the rows in tblstockingorders (something similar to your query above) and set their last status, but this would give you best overall performance as these two tables grow.

Answer (score 1):

The `EXPLAIN` statement can be very useful when trying to track down the cause of a slow query. There's some great explanations of how to use the `EXPLAIN` statement and how to interpret its results [here](http://hackmysql.com/case1) (with more real-word examples at /case{2..4}) and the official documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want only the orders with a certain status/type...

```
    SELECT tblstockingorders.*, tblstatushistory.status AS actualStatus
    FROM tblstockingorders
    INNER JOIN tblstatushistory 
        ON tblstatushistory.id=tblstockingorders.stockingorderid 
    WHERE tblstatushistory.itemtype=2
     AND  tblstatushistory.status=0
```

editted version

```
    SELECT tblstockingorders.*, actualStatus.actualStatus
    FROM tblstockingorders
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT ID, MAX(Status) AS actualStatus
        FROM tblstatushistory 
        GROUP BY ID
    ) actualStatus
        ON actualStatus.id=tblstockingorders.stockingorderid 
    WHERE tblstatushistory.itemtype=2
        AND  tblstatushistory.status=0
```

Comment: this would work if each order had a single status, but i keep a history of statuses as individual entries, and i just want the latest one. so every order has a status history of 0 at some point (0 is the initial state), but some have moved on to other statuses. doing this would pull every single order.

Comment: Assuming(possibly poor assumption on my part) your statuses increase in value you could use a query in in the join instead.

Comment: they don't increase in value, but their ID's increment. brilliant suggestion! i will give it a shot :)

Comment: there is a `modified` timestamp. is there any way to pull the latest history timestamp for a given record?